# Batch - SQLCMD with Parameters not working in for loop

Tags: batch-file, sqlcmd

I am creating a batch script that loops through all the results from an SQL result set returned via SQLCMD

I have done this before with no problems, however the difference this time is that the SQL script accepts a parameter and this seems to be what is causing problems

If I create a batch file with the following code, the statement returns the records as expected:

```
sqlcmd -S MyServer\MyInstance -d MyDatabase -U sa -P MyPassword -i C:\MySQLFile.sql -v Surname="Smith"
```

This returns all the records where surname is Smith to console window. All OK so far.

However, lets say I want to do something for each record returned in the FOR loop

```
FOR /f "tokens=1" %%i IN ('sqlcmd -S MyServer\MyInstance -d MyDatabase -U sa -P MyPassword -i C:\MySQLFile.sql -v Surname="Smith"') DO (
    echo hello
)
```

I get

```
Sqlcmd: 'Smith': Invalid argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

If i change the SQL script so it has no parameters, I can do the same (but remove -v and it works:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1" %%i IN ('sqlcmd -S MyServer\MyInstance -d MyDatabase -U sa -P MyPassword -i C:\MySQLFile.sql) DO (
echo hello
)
```

Not sure if there is some special way I need to deal with the SQL CMD parameters inside the FOR loop?

PS, this problem has been anonymised for post on here, I am obviously not really writing a program that writes "hello" for every Smith in a database!

Comment: The equal sign is handled as a delimiter and removed. Try with `-v Surname^="Smith"`

Comment: Thanks, that works!